# jQuery UI datepicker crash on dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm loading a dialog page with jQuery UI and the load function:

```
$("#update_link").dialog({
  modal: false,
  height: 370,
  width: 900,
  title: 'עדכן קישור',
  open: function () {
    $(this).load("<?= site_url()?>/links/show_update?id="+rel+"&rand="+rand());
  }
});
```

Inside the dialog there is an input-text with id "add_time". In this input there is a datepicker:

```
$(".float_form[rel='<?=$id;?>'] #add_time").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "<?=base_url()?>/images/icons/new.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) { alert("die"); }
});
```

When I run it, the first time it works fine. Then I'm closing the dialog and change the link that opens the dialog (with Ajax). If I click again on the input-text with the datepicker, I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined

Because of this error I can't click on any date inside the datepicker. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry about my bad English, and thank you :)

Comment: where is the currentDay property set?

Comment: is not set by me, i think it sets automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:
All you need is to replace the `id="add_time"` to `class="add_time"`

Code:

```
$(".add_time").datepicker();
```

Comment: Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you messed with destroy of datepiccker, here is example:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">

</div>
<button id="ds">dialog show</button>

<script>
$(function(){$('#ds').click(function() {
    var datep = $('<input type="text" id="datep">');
    datep.datepicker();
    var dlg = $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: false,
        open: function() {
            var e = $(this);
            e.html('');
            e.append(datep);

            console.log(datep);
        },
        close: function() {
            datep.datepicker("destroy");
        }

    });
});
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5ZWm/13/

the moral: use desroy when closing dialog, not datepicker.

Comment: I can not use this code, because the input text is taken directly from the load functions. Have you any idea how to do it with load?

Comment: you still can, just destroy datepicker on dialog close, use e.find() to get the datepicker input, with jsfiddle i can't show you with load().

Comment: in `close: function ()` i try to use this code: `$(this).find(".float_form[rel="+rel+"] #add_time").datepicker("destroy");` It still doesn't work

Comment: check with console.log() what your find returns it looks overcomplicated

Comment: I get this: `[<input type=​"text" value=​"03/​08/​2012" id=​"add_time" class>​]`